# ElastAlert2 No mapping found

Tags: opensearch, elastalert2

I'm trying set ElastAlert for Opensearch 2.8.

**I Write config**

```
# This is the folder that contains the rule yaml files
# Any .yaml file will be loaded as a rule
rules_folder: /etc/elastalert/rules

# How often ElastAlert will query Elasticsearch
# The unit can be anything from weeks to seconds
run_every:
  minutes: 1

# ElastAlert will buffer results from the most recent
# period of time, in case some log sources are not in real time
buffer_time:
  minutes: 15

# The Elasticsearch hostname for metadata writeback
# Note that every rule can have its own Elasticsearch host
es_host: localhost

# The Elasticsearch port
es_port: 9200

# The AWS region to use. Set this when using AWS-managed elasticsearch
#aws_region: us-east-1

# The AWS profile to use. Use this if you are using an aws-cli profile.
# See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html
# for details
#profile: test

# Optional URL prefix for Elasticsearch
#es_url_prefix: elasticsearch

# Connect with TLS to Elasticsearch
use_ssl: True

# GET request with body is the default option for Elasticsearch.
# If it fails for some reason, you can pass 'GET', 'POST' or 'source'.
# See http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/connection.html?highlight=send_get_body_as#transport
# for details
# es_send_get_body_as: GET

# Option basic-auth username and password for Elasticsearch
es_username: admin
es_password: password

# Use SSL authentication with client certificates client_cert must be
# a pem file containing both cert and key for client
verify_certs: False
#ca_certs: /path/to/cacert.pem
#client_cert: /path/to/client_cert.pem
#client_key: /path/to/client_key.key

# The index on es_host which is used for metadata storage
# This can be a unmapped index, but it is recommended that you run
# elastalert-create-index to set a mapping
writeback_index: elastalert_status
writeback_alias: elastalert_alerts

# If an alert fails for some reason, ElastAlert will retry
# sending the alert until this time period has elapsed
alert_time_limit:
  days: 2
```

**... And rule file**

```
# Alert when the rate of events exceeds a threshold
.
# (Optional)
# Elasticsearch host
es_host: localhost
.
# (Optional)
# Elasticsearch port
es_port: 9200
.
# (OptionaL) Connect with SSL to Elasticsearch
use_ssl: True


ssl_show_warn: False


verify_certs: False


.
# (Optional) basic-auth username and password for Elasticsearch
# es_username: admin
# es_password: ytnhfvgkby
.
# (Required)
# Rule name, must be unique
name: Loopdetect
.
# (Required)
# Type of alert.
# the frequency rule type alerts when num_events events occur with timeframe time
type: any
.
# (Required)
# Index to search, wildcard supported
index: syslog-20221104
.
# (Required, frequency specific)
# Alert when this many documents matching the query occur within a timeframe
num_events: 1
.
# (Required, frequency specific)
# num_events must occur within this amount of time to trigger an alert
timeframe:
  hours: 24
.
# (Required)
# A list of Elasticsearch filters used for find events
# These filters are joined with AND and nested in a filtered query
# For more info: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html
# filter:
# - term:
#    process.name: "JUSTME"

filter:
- query:
    query_string:
      query: "message: *loop*"


# (Required)
# The alert is use when a match is found
alert:
- "email"
.
# (required, email specific)
# a list of email addresses to send alerts to
email:
- "myemail"
```

But when I try check this rule.
I get error:

**elastalert-test-rule rules/loopdetect_alert.yaml**

```
INFO:elastalert:Note: In debug mode, alerts will be logged to console but NOT actually sent.
            To send them but remain verbose, use --verbose instead.
WARNING:elasticsearch:POST https://localhost:9200/syslog-20221104/_search?ignore_unavailable=true&size=1 [status:400 request:0.048s]
Error running your filter:
RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', {'error': {'root_cause': [{'type': 'query_shard_exception', 'reason': 'No mapping found for [@timestamp] in order to sort on', 'index': 'syslog-20221104', 'index_uuid': 'BG6MQmmYRUyLBY3tEFykEQ'}], 'type': 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'reason': 'all shards failed', 'phase': 'query', 'grouped': True, 'failed_shards': [{'shard': 0, 'index': 'syslog-20221104', 'node': '5spTsU7-QienT8Jn064MMA', 'reason': {'type': 'query_shard_exception', 'reason': 'No mapping found for [@timestamp] in order to sort on', 'index': 'syslog-20221104', 'index_uuid': 'BG6MQmmYRUyLBY3tEFykEQ'}}]}, 'status': 400})
INFO:elastalert:Note: In debug mode, alerts will be logged to console but NOT actually sent.
                To send them but remain verbose, use --verbose instead.
INFO:elastalert:1 rules loaded
INFO:apscheduler.scheduler:Adding job tentatively -- it will be properly scheduled when the scheduler starts
WARNING:elasticsearch:POST https://localhost:9200/syslog-20221104/_search?_source_includes=%40timestamp%2C%2A&ignore_unavailable=true&scroll=30s&size=10000 [status:400 request:0.039s]
ERROR:elastalert:Error running query: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'No mapping found for [@timestamp] in order to sort on')
{"writeback": {"elastalert_error": {"message": "Error running query: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'No mapping found for [@timestamp] in order to sort on')", "traceback": ["Traceback (most recent call last):", "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/elastalert2-2.8.0-py3.11.egg/elastalert/elastalert.py\", line 370, in get_hits", "    res = self.thread_data.current_es.search(", "          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^", "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py\", line 152, in _wrapped", "    return func(*args, params=params, headers=headers, **kwargs)", "           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^", "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py\", line 1658, in search", "    return self.transport.perform_request(", "           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^", "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py\", line 392, in perform_request", "    raise e", "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py\", line 358, in perform_request", "    status, headers_response, data = connection.perform_request(", "                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^", "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_requests.py\", line 199, in perform_request", "    self._raise_error(response.status_code, raw_data)", "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py\", line 315, in _raise_error", "    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(", "elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'No mapping found for [@timestamp] in order to sort on')"], "data": {"rule": "Loopdetect", "query": {"query": {"bool": {"filter": {"bool": {"must": [{"range": {"@timestamp": {"gt": "2022-11-03T12:12:39.618168Z", "lte": "2022-11-03T12:27:39.618168Z"}}}, {"query_string": {"query": "message: *loop*"}}]}}}}, "sort": [{"@timestamp": {"order": "asc"}}]}}}}}
```

But if I try get data by CURL, it's ok

**curl -X GET 'https://localhost:9200/syslog-20221104/_search?ignore_unavailable=true&size=1' -u 'admin:password' --insecure**

```
{"took":4,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":{"value":10000,"relation":"gte"},"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"syslog-20221104","_id":"_bSKQYQB_cpiH2g_hgvj","_score":1.0,"_source":{"host":"10.53.0.35","hostname":"10.53.0.35","message":"Port 2 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex","source_ip":"91.195.230.4","source_type":"syslog","timestamp":"2022-11-04T07:28:27Z"}}]}}
```

Help me please understand, what I do wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I add `timestamp_field: timestamp`.
And all work fine!